# Detecting slow and fast-flick in android

Tags: android

I am working on a project and there is a need of adding flicking in some objects. But the problem is to differentiate the flicking motion that either the flick is fast or slow. **Can I recognize the flicking speed in android?**

Code so far is;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `float velocityX, float velocityY` of the `onFling` event exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1):

[Android's Documentation for OnFling](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float)) should give you the answer:

> velocityX float: The velocity of this fling measured in pixels per second along the x axis.
>   velocityY   float: The velocity of this fling measured in pixels per second along the y axis.

you overrode

```
 @Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
    return true;
}
```

Which should be called every time a fling movement is detected. Hence, just measure the velocityX and velocityY according to which axis you are tracking for movement.